# Leave many spaces between words using paste0() in R

Tags: r

I use `paste0()` to print the text below but I want to set distance by using many spaces between `(Form 1003)` and `No`

```
paste0("Mortgage Application (Form 1003)",'','',"No",collapse = '').
```

The result should be like: Mortgage Application (Form 1003)________No. The________ is the white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `sep` argument in paste:

```
paste("Mortgage Application (Form 1003)", "No", sep = '              ')
[1] "Mortgage Application (Form 1003)              No"
```

Comment: Could u check this one? -edited the Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971953/set-white-space-in-menuitem-title-in-shiny-dashboard

Answer (score 2):

You can add variable number of spaces using `strrep`

```
paste0("Mortgage Application (Form 1003)",strrep(' ', 10),"No")
#[1] "Mortgage Application (Form 1003)          No"

paste0("Mortgage Application (Form 1003)",strrep(' ', 20),"No")
#[1] "Mortgage Application (Form 1003)                    No"
```

Comment: Could u check this one? -edited the Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971953/set-white-space-in-menuitem-title-in-shiny-dashboard