# Set white space in menuItem title in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I have the basic shiny dashboard below in which I use menuItems. Im trying to set distance between `(Form 1003)` and `No` but I cannot achieve it with even 2 different ways.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
shinyApp(
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
    dashboardSidebar(width=400,sidebarMenu(id = "menu", sidebarMenuOutput("menu"))),
    dashboardBody(
    )
),



server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$menu <- renderMenu({
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem(paste0("Mortgage Application (Form 1003)",strrep(' ', 10),"No"), tabName = "plots"),
            menuItem(paste("Mortgage Application (Form 1003)", "No", sep = '              '), tabName = "plots2")


        )
    })

}
)
```

Comment: I guess the above link answers your question. Did you try it?

Comment: yes it did tnx !